# Why do images (png format) saved in app's document directory get deleted on app upgrade while other db files remain intact on iOS devices?

Tags: ios

I'm saving banners (png images) of my application in app's Document directory which gets deleted when upgrading the app to next version where as as per Apple Guideline it should be remain intact. Can anyone tell why this is happening?
Is there any limit on data size of each file or all files, the total size of all banners is 500MB?